# Request for help to tidy up code involving arrays and loops

Tags: java, array, classes

I posted the following code [on here a few days ago](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/17992/request-for-help-to-tidy-up-code-involving-arrays-and-for-statements):

```
public class Practical4_Assessed
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        Random numberGenerator = new Random();
        int[] arrayOfGenerator = new int[100];
        int[] countOfArray = new int[10];
        int count;

        for (int countOfGenerator = 0; countOfGenerator < 100; countOfGenerator++)
        {
            count = numberGenerator.nextInt(10);
            countOfArray[count]++;
            arrayOfGenerator[countOfGenerator] = count + 1;
        }

        int countOfNumbersOnLine = 0;
        for (int countOfOutput = 0; countOfOutput < 100; countOfOutput++)
        {
            if (countOfNumbersOnLine == 10)
            {
                System.out.println("");
                countOfNumbersOnLine = 0;
                countOfOutput--;
            }
            else
            {
                if (arrayOfGenerator[countOfOutput] == 10)
                {
                    System.out.print(arrayOfGenerator[countOfOutput] + "  ");
                    countOfNumbersOnLine++;
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.print(arrayOfGenerator[countOfOutput] + "   ");
                    countOfNumbersOnLine++;
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("");

        for (int countOfNumbers = 0; countOfNumbers < countOfArray.length; countOfNumbers++)
            System.out.println("The number " + (countOfNumbers + 1)
                    + " occurs " + countOfArray[countOfNumbers] + " times.");

        System.out.println("");

        for (int countOfNumbers = 0; countOfNumbers < countOfArray.length; countOfNumbers++)
        {
            if (countOfNumbers != 9)
                System.out.print((countOfNumbers + 1) + "   ");
            else
                System.out.print((countOfNumbers + 1) + "  ");

            for (int a = 0; a < countOfArray[countOfNumbers]; a++)
            {
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }

        System.out.println("");

        int max = 0;
        int test = 0;
        for (int counter = 0; counter < countOfArray.length; counter++)
        {
            if (countOfArray[counter] > max)
            {
                max = countOfArray[counter];
                test = counter + 1;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("The number that appears the most is " + test);

    }
}
```

I posted it for help on how to tidy it up - the suggestion I got was to add methods to break the code down into more manageable, testable sections.
However, despite spending the best part of two days trying, I can't get my head around how to do this. Everytime I try, I either generate compile-time or run-time errors.

Would anyone mind showing me even one or two of the methods I could use, so I can work from that?

Comment: Maybe try to do it in very small steps? And make sure that each step doesn't break anything. [The other question](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/17992/request-for-help-to-tidy-up-code-involving-arrays-and-for-statements) may give inspiration to the next helper in line.

Comment: @froderik: I posted a solution I came up with using methods. I am sure it's still inefficient, but it'll do for now! Thanks for your help on both this thread and the previous one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After stressing about it for about two hours, I got the methods sorted, so I'll answer my own question. Please note - I'm just a beginner and I'm sure there are plenty of things that could be done even more efficiently!

```
import java.util.Random;
// Imports Java random number generator.

public class Practical4_Assessed_with_Methods 
{
static int[] randomNumbers = new int[100];
static int[] countNumbers = new int[10];
// Two arrays declared, one to hold 100 elements, the other 10.

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    programExplanation();
    generateNumbers(randomNumbers, countNumbers);
    printNumbers(randomNumbers);
    generateNumberOfOccurences(countNumbers);
    generateAsteriskPattern(countNumbers);
    findMaxValues(countNumbers);
    // Code is broken down into five method calls (to make each section more manageable and testable).
}

static void programExplanation()
{
    System.out.println("This program will generate 100 random integers between 1 and 10. " +
            "It will then output them in rows of 10.");
    System.out.println("Following this, it will output how often each integer occured in " +
            "the array.");
    System.out.println("It will also output this information in a horizontal bar chart of " +
            "asterisks.");
    System.out.println("Finally, it will output which number, or numbers appeared most often");
    System.out.println("");
}

static void generateNumbers(int[] arrayOfGenerator, int[] countArray)
{
    Random numberGenerator = new Random ();
    for (int countOfGenerator = 0; countOfGenerator < 100; countOfGenerator++) // For loop continues 100 times.
    {
        int count = numberGenerator.nextInt(10);
        countArray[count]++;
        arrayOfGenerator[countOfGenerator] = count + 1;
    }
    /*  A random number (from 0 and 9) is generated and stored in count.
     *  Whatever number is generated, that element number of countArray is incremented by 1.
     *  E.g. If random number generated = 4, fourth element of countArray (i.e. element 3) is increased by 1.
     *  The element of arrayOfGenerator (determined by the loop) is given the value of count + 1.
     *  This is because the numberGenerator creates integers from 0 and 9 - we want from 1 and 10.

     *  This coding is beneficial as both arrays are filled at the same time, which saves processing time.
     */
}

static void printNumbers(int[] arrayOfGenerator)
{
    int countOfNumbersOnLine = 0;
    for (int countOfOutput = 0; countOfOutput < 100; countOfOutput++)
    {
        if (countOfNumbersOnLine % 10 == 0)
            System.out.println("");
        //  Takes a new line when 10 integers have been printed on a line.

            if (arrayOfGenerator[countOfOutput] == 10)
            {
                System.out.print(arrayOfGenerator[countOfOutput] + "  ");
                countOfNumbersOnLine++;
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.print(arrayOfGenerator[countOfOutput] + "   ");
                countOfNumbersOnLine++;
            }

    }
    /*  Used to calculate the amount of integers on a line and the spacing between them.
     *  If the arrayOfGenerator is 10, it takes two spaces, else it takes 3 spaces (to ensure proper spacing).
     *  This is needed because the numeral 10 has two characters, as opposed to 1-9.
     */

    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("");
}

static void generateNumberOfOccurences(int[] countOfArray)
{
    for (int countOfNumbers = 0; countOfNumbers < countOfArray.length; countOfNumbers++)
        System.out.println("The number " + (countOfNumbers + 1) + " occurs " + countOfArray[countOfNumbers] + " times.");
    System.out.println("");
    /*  For loop continues for entire length of countOfArray (i.e. 10 times)
     *  Prints out how often each random number occured.
     */
}

static void generateAsteriskPattern(int[] countOfArray)
{
    for (int countOfNumbers = 0; countOfNumbers < countOfArray.length; countOfNumbers++)
    {
        if (countOfNumbers != 9)
            System.out.print((countOfNumbers + 1) + "   ");
        else
            System.out.print((countOfNumbers + 1) + "  ");

        for (int asteriskCount = 0; asteriskCount < countOfArray[countOfNumbers]; asteriskCount++)
            System.out.print("*");
        System.out.println("");
    }
    System.out.println("");
    /*  For loop continues for entire length of countOfArray (i.e. 10 times)
     *  First if/else statement determines how many spaces are taken after numeral and before asterisks.
     *  This is used to ensure all asterisks are vertically aligned when output.
     *  Second for statement runs on each element of countOfArray, outputting asterisks for as long as array lasts. 
     *  For example, if element 0 has the value 3, 3 asterisks are output. 
     */
}

static void findMaxValues(int[] countOfArray)
{
    int max = 0;
    for (int counter = 0; counter < countOfArray.length; counter++)
    {
        if (countOfArray[counter] > max)
        {
            max = countOfArray[counter];
        }
    }

    System.out.print("Number(s) that appears the most:");
    /*  For loop continues for entire length of countOfArray (i.e. 10 times) and compares each value to max.
     *  If value compared is larger than the max value, it becomes new max value.
     *  By the end of this loop, largest value in the array is stored in max. 
     */

    for(int checkValue = 0; checkValue < countOfArray.length; checkValue++)
        if(countOfArray[checkValue] == max)
            System.out.print(" " + (checkValue + 1));
    System.out.print(".");
    /*  For loop continues for entire length of countOfArray (i.e. 10 times)
     *  If value of element scanned is equal to the value in max, it is output. 
     */
}
}
```

Andrew

Comment: way to go. much easier to understand now!

Comment: comment before the code not after, it is easier to read and understand. Overall very good improvement.

Comment: @niks: Given your language, you'll likely be banned from here too. On the site I posted under your answer advice on how to improve your future posts. I suggest you clean up your language and follow it.

Answer (score 3):

(I am not yet allowed to make a comment, this post refers to the authors answer)

Be careful with code comments. I do not like the "comment as much as possible" way, this way has some serious flaws.

In your example, you should not add trivial comments. You do not have to write `For loop continues for entire length of countOfArray`, because this is clear from the loop body. Or `// Imports Java random number generator.`. This is clearly stated in the code before.
I would advise to put the comments above the corresponding lines of code.

You should only add comments, if non trivial things are happening. Even more, a huge amount of comments is a sign that this part of code should perhaps be changed to make it more clear.

If you want to test your methods (as stated in one comment), you should not do a print to sys.out inside it. It is very hard to test this things (You have to redirect sys.out or catch it somewhere else). But well, one can discuss if this is necessary in this small exercise.

For `generateNumberOfOccurences` and `generateAsteriskPattern` I would use `print` instead of `generate` as for `printNumbers`, because this describes what is happening inside.

Perhaps you want to think about making it more flexible. You should prefer a `List` instead of an `Array`. You could use `StringBuilder` instead of String concatenation with the `+`. You could use a `Map` to calculate the occurrences.

If you are interested, I have appended a fast typed down implementation (this means, it does not check for all possible problems or caveats). You can scroll around and get some ideas how to handle some things. But be aware, that not everything is necessarily the best way. It mostly reflects my own experience.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.Random;

public class test {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final int amountOfNumbers = 100;
        final int randomStart = 1;
        final int randomEndInclusive = 10;
        final List<Integer> randomNumbers = getRandomNumbers(amountOfNumbers, randomStart, randomEndInclusive);

        final int columnsPerLine = 10;
        System.out.println(getTableAsString(randomNumbers, columnsPerLine));

        final Map<Integer, Integer> mapNumberToOccurence = getOccurenceMap(randomNumbers);

        System.out.println(getOccurenceAsString(mapNumberToOccurence));

        final String chartIndicator = "*";
        System.out.println(getOccurenceChartAsString(mapNumberToOccurence, chartIndicator));

        System.out.println(getHighestAppearanceAsString(mapNumberToOccurence));
    }

    private static List<Integer> getRandomNumbers(final int amountOfNumbers, final int randomStart, final int randomEndInclusive) {
        final List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
        final Random random = new Random();
        final int randomEndExclusive = randomEndInclusive + 1 - randomStart;
        for (int i = 0; i < amountOfNumbers; i++)
            result.add(randomStart + random.nextInt(randomEndExclusive));
        return result;
    }

    private static String getTableAsString(final List<Integer> randomNumbers, final int columnsPerLine) {
        int counter = 0;
        int maxNumber = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        for (final Integer randomNumbersItem : randomNumbers)
            maxNumber = Math.max(maxNumber, randomNumbersItem);
        final int maxWidth = String.valueOf(maxNumber).length();
        final String format = " %" + maxWidth + "d";
        final StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        for (final Integer randomNumbersItem : randomNumbers) {
            ++counter;
            stringBuilder.append(String.format(format, randomNumbersItem)).append(" ");
            if (counter >= columnsPerLine) {
                stringBuilder.append(System.lineSeparator());
                counter = 0;
            }
        }
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }

    private static Map<Integer, Integer> getOccurenceMap(final List<Integer> randomNumbers) {
        final Map<Integer, Integer> mapNumberToOccurence = new HashMap<>();
        for (final Integer randomNumbersItem : randomNumbers) {
            Integer occurence = mapNumberToOccurence.get(randomNumbersItem);
            if (occurence == null) occurence = 0;
            mapNumberToOccurence.put(randomNumbersItem, occurence + 1);
        }
        return mapNumberToOccurence;
    }

    private static String getOccurenceAsString(final Map<Integer, Integer> mapNumberToOccurence) {
        final List<Integer> allNumbers = new ArrayList<>(mapNumberToOccurence.keySet());
        Collections.sort(allNumbers);
        final StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        for (final Integer allNumbersItem : allNumbers)
            stringBuilder.append("The number ").append(allNumbersItem).append(" occurs ").append(mapNumberToOccurence.get(allNumbersItem)).append(" times.")
                    .append(System.lineSeparator());
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }

    private static String getOccurenceChartAsString(final Map<Integer, Integer> mapNumberToOccurence, final String chartIndicator) {
        final List<Integer> allNumbers = new ArrayList<>(mapNumberToOccurence.keySet());
        Collections.sort(allNumbers);
        final int maxWidth = String.valueOf(allNumbers.get(allNumbers.size() - 1)).length();
        final String format = " %" + maxWidth + "d";
        final StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        for (final Integer allNumbersItem : allNumbers) {
            stringBuilder.append(String.format(format, allNumbersItem)).append(": ");
            final int occurence = mapNumberToOccurence.get(allNumbersItem);
            for (int i = 0; i < occurence; i++)
                stringBuilder.append(chartIndicator);
            stringBuilder.append(System.lineSeparator());
        }
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }

    private static String getHighestAppearanceAsString(final Map<Integer, Integer> mapNumberToOccurence) {
        int counter = 0;
        final String separator = ", ";
        final int highestAppearance = getHighestAppearance(mapNumberToOccurence);
        final StringBuilder stringBuilderNumbers = new StringBuilder();
        for (final Entry<Integer, Integer> mapNumberToOccurenceEntrySetItem : mapNumberToOccurence.entrySet()) {
            if (mapNumberToOccurenceEntrySetItem.getValue() == highestAppearance) {
                ++counter;
                stringBuilderNumbers.append(mapNumberToOccurenceEntrySetItem.getKey()).append(separator);
            }
        }

        if (counter == 0) return "";
        if (counter > 0) // we have results, remove the last separator
            stringBuilderNumbers.setLength(stringBuilderNumbers.length() - separator.length());
        final StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder("Number");
        if (counter > 1) // we have more than 1 result, make it plural
            result.append("s");
        result.append(" that appear");
        if (counter == 1) // we have 1 result, append the third person singular s
            result.append("s");
        result.append(" the most: ").append(stringBuilderNumbers).append(".");

        return result.toString();
    }

    private static int getHighestAppearance(final Map<Integer, Integer> mapNumberToOccurence) {
        int highestAppearance = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        for (final Integer mapNumberToOccurenceValuesItem : mapNumberToOccurence.values())
            highestAppearance = Math.max(highestAppearance, mapNumberToOccurenceValuesItem);
        return highestAppearance;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1. In [my answer](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/17992/request-for-help-to-tidy-up-code-involving-arrays-and-for-statements/18051#18051) to the [original question](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/17992/9390), I also suggested using a `Map`. I'd appreciate some feedback on that answer, actually, as it took a significant amount of time to write down.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have not enough reputation here to make comments anywhere but my own answers :(

Comment: @codesparkle: Just letting you know that Uni work has gotten a bit hectic lately, and that's why I haven't responded to all your help. We've a uni project due on Wed, two practicals on Mon and two tests on Tues - I will get back to you though with how I've gotten on.

Comment: @tb-: Just letting you know my lecturer told me about the commenting and I've whacked it way down. Thanks!

Comment: @andrew no worries.